# JointJS Basic understanding

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, web, jointjs

I am following this tutorial here :

http://jointjs.com/tutorial/html-elements

I have two small questions :

1)- What is this "joint.util.deepSupplement" ? what is its purpose ?

2)- How is this custom view working here in this code ?

```
// Create a custom view for that element that displays an HTML div above it.
// -------------------------------------------------------------------------
joint.shapes.html.ElementView = joint.dia.ElementView.extend({

template: [
    '<div class="html-element">',
    '<button class="delete">x</button>',
    '<label></label>',
    '<span></span>', '<br/>',
    '<select><option>--</option><option>one</option><option>two</option></select>',
    '<input type="text" value="I\'m HTML input" />',
    '</div>'
].join(''),

initialize: function() {
    _.bindAll(this, 'updateBox');
    joint.dia.ElementView.prototype.initialize.apply(this, arguments);

    this.$box = $(_.template(this.template)());
    // Prevent paper from handling pointerdown.
    this.$box.find('input,select').on('mousedown click', function(evt) { evt.stopPropagation(); });
    // This is an example of reacting on the input change and storing the input data in the cell model.
    this.$box.find('input').on('change', _.bind(function(evt) {
        this.model.set('input', $(evt.target).val());
    }, this));
    this.$box.find('select').on('change', _.bind(function(evt) {
        this.model.set('select', $(evt.target).val());
    }, this));
    this.$box.find('select').val(this.model.get('select'));
    this.$box.find('.delete').on('click', _.bind(this.model.remove, this.model));
    // Update the box position whenever the underlying model changes.
    this.model.on('change', this.updateBox, this);
    // Remove the box when the model gets removed from the graph.
    this.model.on('remove', this.removeBox, this);

    this.updateBox();
},
render: function() {
    joint.dia.ElementView.prototype.render.apply(this, arguments);
    this.paper.$el.prepend(this.$box);
    this.updateBox();
    return this;
},
updateBox: function() {
    // Set the position and dimension of the box so that it covers the JointJS element.
    var bbox = this.model.getBBox();
    // Example of updating the HTML with a data stored in the cell model.
    this.$box.find('label').text(this.model.get('label'));
    this.$box.find('span').text(this.model.get('select'));
    this.$box.css({ width: bbox.width, height: bbox.height, left: bbox.x, top: bbox.y, transform: 'rotate(' + (this.model.get('angle') || 0) + 'deg)' });
},
removeBox: function(evt) {
    this.$box.remove();
}
});
```

Also i wonder what are the first two lines in the initialize function doing where it says _.bindAll and in the next line joint.dia.ElementView.... ?

Answer (score 2):

- `joint.util.deepSupplement` behaves exact the same as lodash `_.defaultsDeep` (https://lodash.com/docs#defaultsDeep)
- `joint.dia.ElementView.prototype.initialize.apply(this, arguments);` This is way how to supply call the 'base class' method in js. In this snippet it calls the initialize method on base class, `joint.dia.ElementView`.
- bindAll: This is lodash syntax sugar for dealing with call context ('this'). All syntax bellow are equivalent

1.
`_.bindAll(this, 'updateBox');
this.model.on('change', this.updateBox);`

2.
`this.model.on('change', _.bind(this.updateBox, this));`

3.
`this.model.on('change', this.updateBox, this);`

4.
`var self = this;
this.model.on('change', function() {
    self.updateBox();
});`

Comment: Ok so please correct me...from what i,ve read and understood from the link you shared is that...joint.util.deepSupplement is used to change the nature of the object... For example in the link you shared : if there are two objects of same name "user" and you use this "joint.util.deepSupplement" then this will assign the values of second object "age:36" to first object "name:barney".....okay but what about the name property in the second object which is "name:fred"...what happens to that.

Comment: And about bindAll you said...: This is lodash syntax sugar for dealing with call context ('this')....syntax sugar ?? What kind of sugar is that ?... :-p

Comment: 'fred' is not used as the name is already defined with 'barney'. https://lodash.com/docs#defaults  - couldn't be explained better